# How to get specific value that is present within an anchor tag

Tags: apex

```
String v1 = '<a name="41" href="/pw/moneyout/vendor_detail.do?entityID=4000&action=ViewBill&recentItem=true&tabIndex=4&vendorLedgerView.month=3&vendorLedgerView.year=2016&itemID=877&ReportEntityID=668">41</a>'

String v2 = '<a name="43 Ave" href="/pw/properties/building_detail.do?entityID=667&ReportEntityID=668">43 Ave</a>'
```

using the below will yield the inner text value,

```
v1.replaceAll('\\<.*?\\>', '');
v2.replaceAll('\\<.*?\\>', '');
```

Likewise i need the value of itemID (From 1st Anchor tag) and entityID (From 2nd Anchor tag) that i mentioned above. How to get the value using apex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String v1 = '<a name="41" href="/pw/moneyout/vendor_detail.do?entityID=4000&action=ViewBill&recentItem=true&tabIndex=4&vendorLedgerView.month=3&vendorLedgerView.year=2016&itemID=877&ReportEntityID=668">41</a>'

string href1 = .. do some xml parsing here ...;

System.PageReference pageReference = new System.PageReference( href1 );
Map<String,String> parameters = pageReference.getParameters();

system.debug(parameters.get('itemID'));
```

Comment: It would be so helpful for me if you could post the xml parsing code too. Also if possible post the code how to get the specific value using regex.

Comment: Never done it, trying to find something useful online now.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. If you also find a way to get the values using regex then please post it here.

Comment: Regex generally isn't the right tool for parsing HTML. Using [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) and [Dom.XmlNode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm%23apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode) takes a little bit of setup, but it was made for this kind of thing. It's hard to work out an example in a comment, but the gist of it is: Create a new document, load your string, get the root node, use `getAttributeValue()` to pull the `href` out.

Comment: @Derek Thanks for the information. I will try it out.